# Distance between a given point and a convex polytope

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

Let $\mathcal{P} := \{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k \} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the convex hull of $\mathcal{P}$. What is the minimal Euclidean distance between $q \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and any point in $\mathcal{C}$?

I am more interested in cases where $ 2 \leq k \leq 100$ and $d \approx 1000$. It is also [argued](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions) that the Euclidean distance might be non-intuitive in high dimensions. In that case, what other distance functions could be considered?

Comment: I am aware that polytopes might not be properly defined when k <= d. In that case, I am looking for the distance between the point q and the convex set of P (for instance, the distance of q from a line segment between two points in 3-dimensional space).

Comment: You should use the term "convex hull". See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41000123/5802041)

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3707984/339790)

Answer (score 1):

A point $p$ in the convex combination of the points satisfies $p=\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i x_i$ for $\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i = 1$ and $\lambda_{i} \geq 0$. If you are interested in the max-norm, then this is representable by a Linear program (which you can solve very quickly):

$$
\min M
$$
\begin{align}
&q_j - \sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i x_{ij}\le M  \quad j=1\ldots, d\\
&\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i x_{ij} - q_j \le M  \quad j=1\ldots, d\\
&\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i=1\\
&\lambda_i\ge 0,\quad\quad \quad~~~~~~~ i=1,\ldots,k.
\end{align}
This is an $O(k d)$ constraint matrix which is okay for your constraints in practice.

If you still want the Eucledian distance, then you can solve a similar quadratic program:

$$
\min \sum_{j=1}^d \left(q_j - \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i x_{ij}  \right)^2
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i=1\\
&\lambda_i\ge 0,\quad\quad \quad~~~~~~~ i=1,\ldots,k.
\end{align}

This is a $O(k^2)$ sized quadratic in $\lambda_i$ variables. This can also be solved with a convex/quadratic programming solver and would be very fast to solve for your sizes.